# How to generate a random key for AES Encryption?

Tags: encryption, rust, openssl, actix-web

I am using the openssl crate to generate a random key every time I receive a request to my endpoint. I will use the newly-generated key to encrypt the request data and send it back as a response.

```
use openssl::rsa::{Rsa, Padding};
use openssl::aes::{AesKey, aes_ige};
use openssl::symm::Mode;
use openssl::rand::rand_bytes;

let mut buf = [0; 128];
rand_bytes(&mut buf).unwrap();
let aeskey = AesKey::new_encrypt(&buf).unwrap();
```

When the `AesKey::new_encrypt` method is executed, I get the following error:

```
thread 'actix-rt:worker:3' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: KeyError(())', src/**/**.rs:23:18
```

My requirement is that the key needs to be random and unique for every request.

Edit 1:

Thank you for the answer. Now I have changed the size and I am now able get a AesKey.

The changed code:

```
    let message = "
    {
        \"id\": 1,
        \"name\": \"xyzab\"
    }".to_string();

    let mut buf = [0; 16];
    rand_bytes(&mut buf).unwrap();
    let aeskey = AesKey::new_encrypt(&buf).unwrap();
    let mut iv = *b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x0E\x0F\
    \x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F";
    let mut outbuf = [0u8; 16];
    aes_ige(message.as_bytes(), &mut outbuf, &aeskey, &mut iv, Mode::Encrypt);
```

When I execute this, I get an error from aes_ige method saying:

```
'assertion failed: in_.len() == out.len()', /Users/shyamsundarb/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-0.10.29/src/aes.rs:142:9
```

I tried increasing the outbuf size but still I got the same error as mentioned above.

I went through the documentation and it stated:

> Panics if in_ is not the same length as out, if that length is not a multiple of 16, or if iv is not at least 32 bytes.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Edit 2:

Thank you for the inputs. I was able to solve this by resizing the input and output buffers to the same size that is a multiple of 16.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: Understood. I've marked the original answer as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let mut buf = [0; 128];
> ```

You're providing a 128 *bytes* buffer as key.

Per the documentation for new_encrypt:

> Returns an error if the key is not 128, 192, or 256 *bits*.

Your key is 4 times too big, and I'd guess 8 times bigger than what you were expecting.

Comment: Hey thank you! That solved the original error. Additionally I am getting an error when I run aes_ige method. I've added an edit to the question with more details.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear? Your message is about 50 bytes (I get 53 pasting it into a separate buffer but not knowing the context it could be a bit off), which is neither the length of your output buffer (16) nor a multiple of 16, both of which are explicitly documented requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to encrypt it by resizing the buffer to multiples of 16.